# Hidden comment retrieving from plugin facebookcomment using API Graph facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

There is facebook Comments Plugin in one page of our client. I get all comments through fb.subcribe events and store them in our database.
Now We have to hide those comments, I have to go to the developers tool to make moderation because I am only the administrator that the client has added.

My question is:
Is there any way to use API facebook Graph to hide the comment? Does someone already make this action by  API graph facebook.

Thanks a lot

Comment: No, that is not possible via API.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it means deleting  is also impossible too